# Modifying Dataframes with Loops

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a folder of .txt documents. Each document from a different year (name of document indicates year). Inside each document is a list of names, sex, and frequency count. Looks like this:

```
Mary,F,7065
Anna,F,2604
Emma,F,2003
```

Naming convention of the documents looks like this:
`'yob1880.txt', 'yob1881.txt', ....`

The goal is to produce a single csv file with columns 'Year', 'Name', 'Sex', and 'Frequency'. To get the year into the dataset for that document, I'm using regex to search for the year and then write that into the dataframe, but I am struggling in incorporating it into a loop for all the documents.

Current code, per @andrewryan:

```
all_files = glob.glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/hw2-starter/yob-names/*.txt')
dataframe_list = []
for file in all_files:
  year_search = re.search('\d{4}', file)
  year = year_search.group()

  temp_dataframe = pd.read_csv(file ,header=None)
  temp_dataframe.columns = ['Name','Sex','Frequency']
  temp_dataframe['Year'] = year
  temp_dataframe.set_index('Year', inplace=True)
  dataframe_list.append(temp_dataframe)

master_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframe_list, ignore_index=True)
master_dataframe.to_csv("yob-names.csv")
```

Output based on code:
[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX31T.png)

What code should reflect:

```
Year Name Sex Frequency
1880 Mary F   7065
1880 Anna F   2604
....
2021 Gil  M   10
```

All of the txt files are now appended, but each text file's data needs to be assigned a row 'Year' that contains the value in the name of the document. So every row in the yob1880.txt file needs column 'Year': 1880, same for 1881 and so on. I'm wondering if this requires a 'with open' function to write the value of the year in the name right to the text file, then pull into a dataframe and concat?

Thanks again for help.

Comment: `year_search = re.search('\d{4}',all_files)` should be `year_search = re.search('\d{4}',file)`

Comment: @AndrewRyan
Thank you for that catch. Fixed as well as one other thing and runs now. Now problem is that it's only grabbing one year and writing the entire dataframe with that one year instead of making individual dataframes with their own years.

Comment: @andrewryan
I updated the comment with new code and where I'm at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to output one file but instead of outputting a file you are constantly rewriting the data over the same file. Therefore you should do something like this to combine all of your dataframes and write them out to a singular file.

```
all_files = glob.glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/hw2-starter/yob-names/*.txt')
dataframe_list = []

for file in all_files:
    year_search = re.search('\d{4}', file)
    year = year_search.group()

    temp_dataframe = pd.read_csv(file ,header=None)
    temp_dataframe.columns = ['Name','Sex','Frequency']
    temp_dataframe['Year'] = year
    temp_dataframe.set_index('Year', inplace=True)
    # add the dataframe to the list
    dataframe_list.append(temp_dataframe)
    
master_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframe_list) # add all of the temp_dataframes to the master_dataframe
# only after finishing your loop would you like to download a version of the csv 
master_dataframe.to_csv("yob-names2.csv")
```

This should fix your issue. If not please update me with what is going wrong with your expected output.

Comment: This got me closer. You were right about it overwriting the last file each time. Output now has the proper rows with one issue - year. Updating post with current output.

Comment: @Brock so then you would remove the `ignore_index=True` from `pd.concat()`, which should look like the code reflected above.

Comment: This totally saved me - I really appreciate your help on this. Had been banging my head on the keyboard for a few days trying to get this right.